# How do I rewrite a text file on the same columns in perl?

Tags: perl

I have an ncl script which I modify inside a perl script, each time I run the Perl script and then call the same ncl script within the perl script.
What I have noticed is that each time I run the perl script, the lines in the ncl script are progressively rewritten to the right. I wonder how far they will go to the right and if the ncl script will still work if the move very far to the right.
I am wondering if it is possible to specify the column from which to start writing. I have no idea if there is a solution to this, apart from manually boving the lines back.
Below are the changes I make to the script.

```
open($NCLSCRPT, " < /home/zmumba/DA/TMINTMAX/Scripts/10_PlotT2mMinMax.ncl") || die "open $NCLSCRPT: failed $! ($^E)";
@scrptlines=<$NCLSCRPT>;
foreach $scrptlines (@scrptlines) {
  if ($scrptlines =~ /(^|\s+)a = addfile/) {
    $scrptlines =~ s/\w+\.nc/Tmin.nc/g;
  }
  if ($scrptlines =~ /wks = gsn_open_wks/) {
    $scrptlines =~ s/\w+_\d{2}/Tmin_$day/g;
  }
  $scrptlines =~ s/\w+ Temperature/Minimum Temperature/g;

  if ($scrptlines =~ /Valid on/) {
    $scrptlines =~ s/$valdate/${day}\/${month}\/${year}/g;
  }
  if ($scrptlines =~ /From 00z on/) {
    $scrptlines =~ s/$wrffcr/T\+00H/g;
    $scrptlines =~ s/$valdate/${day}\/${month}\/${year}/g;
  }
}

close $NCLSCRPT;
open($NCLSCRPT, " > /home/zmumba/DA/TMINTMAX/Scripts/10_PlotT2mMinMax.ncl") || die "open $NCLSCRPT: failed $! ($^E)";
print $NCLSCRPT "@scrptlines\n";
close $NCLSCRPT;
```

To do justice, i am adding a part of the text file I am processing as per request from @Håkon Hægland.
Otherwise the problem has been resolved.

```
begin
;Open input file.
;************************
 DATADir = "./"

 a = addfile(DATADir+"Tmax.nc","r")

 T = wrf_user_getvar(a,"T2",0)
 T = T-273.15
 wrf_smooth_2d( T, 3 )             ; smooth T
 ;printVarSummary(T)
 ;exit

 lat2d    = a->XLAT(:,:)
 lon2d    = a->XLONG(:,:)

 lat      = lat2d(:,0)           ; create classic 1D coordinate arrays
 lon      = lon2d(0,:)
 lat@units= "degrees_north"
 lon@units= "degrees_east"
 lat!0    = "lat"
 lon!0    = "lon"
 lat&lat  =  lat
```

Comment: The regex substitutions could in principle add spaces to the beginning of each line -- but I don't see that.  The only such possibilty in the shown code would be in the variable `$day` -- if it has a space (or a few) at its beginning (which it shouldn't anyway), and if `$validate` (which it replaces) comes at the beginning of its line. But that wouldn't be on _all_ lines...

Comment: Please include a sample input file, together with expected output file. See [mcve] for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding spaces with your final print:

```
print $NCLSCRPT "@scrptlines\n";
```

When you interpolate an array into a string, each element is padded with a space (default value of the `$"` variable). So, when you take the lines from a file, and continuously interpolate them this way, you will add spaces.

It should instead be

```
print $NCLSCRPT @scrptlines;
```

If you never edit the line endings, you don't need to worry about them.